# How to use OpenWebKitSharp library in x64 Bit Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, 64-bit, .net-framework-version, open-webkit-sharp

I want to show web pages in winforms (x64 Bit) application that is running on .Net Framework 4.7.2.

For the achieving above objective I am trying to use OpenWebKitSharp library (OpenWebKitSharp.dll & WebKit.Interop.dll) but I am unable to get their x64 version.